# You have AA in the BB. The BU opens to 3.5x. What is your line?

Tags: poker-theory, poker-strategy, probability, statistics

You have AA in the BB. The BTN opens to 3.5x. What is your line ?

Comment: Which type of players ? LAG / TAG / Maniac ? CG ? Tournament ? HG ? Stacks (short / deep) ? Numbers (like VPIP) ? so many variables here...

Comment: Not folding would be a good start as a line to take. As a general rule you can't go wrong with raising always with aces. But for a more in depth answer see @OldPadawan's advice.

Comment: +1 just for `Not folding would be a good start` :) (even though I did it once in a big tournament, short stack and 1 to go ITM - Button was CL with huge stack)

Comment: Ah that's a little different situation. Yeah I've done it before, what's it called ICM + NASH Equilibrium for those situations?

Comment: I just call it *wisdom* though :)

Comment: So much missing information here:
Cash game or tournament?
What are your relative stack sizes?
Is everyone else besides the button already folded?
Do you have ANY information on the button player?

Comment: If you aren't 3-betting AA in the BB against a BTN open, then you are invited to my home game :)

Answer (score 3):

The standard line would be to re-raise to what ever your defend re-raise is.

Depending on how often the BU raises you should be defending with a re-raise a decent range.  If you defend with 88+ and sometimes just suited connector then AA will not stick out.  Just call with some of your re-raise range sometimes but I would always re-raise AA here.

Give them a chance to re-raise you back in case they have a real hand like KK so you can get it all in.  I have read never slow play the nuts as your opponent might have a hand willing to come along.

Comment: 99.99% of the times I consider reraise to be the optimal play in such a situation, given the fact that the aggressor opens with 3.5x, which is a quite large bet,so he is more likely to have a big hand and then we bump into the scenario you mentioned last. That's true if we are talking deepstack (effect.stack>50BB). In shortstack situations you could maybe call and induce one or two barrels of bluff if you know the opponent is capable of doing so.

Comment: @koita_pisw_sou Don't agree but not going to argue with you.  Short stack is more pot committed so easier to get it in pre flop.

Comment: I would reraise in almost any case, too. What I wanted to underline, was that if you plan to just call and set a trap, it is too risky to do it when being deepstack. However, when shortstack in a tour, it could work as a tricky play in order to lure an opponent with top pair top kicker in (or a bluffy opponent) and take his stack (not the best example as Hellmuth loses, but you get the idea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIC2MQ3A46o)

Answer (score 1):

I believe my line would be ***Woohoo!*** in my best Homer Simpson voice, likely accompanied with a few fist pumps.

*(Note: This likely works best in online play, where your opponent will not see/hear you.)*

I would then make my standard 3-bet for the game situation.

Answer (score 0):

When you have AA, your ultimate goal is to get all the stacks in the middle pre-flop, so always RAISE when you have the option pre-flop with AA.